# Git: Move to previous and next commit

Tags: git, history, commit

I need a way to quickly move to the previous and next commit in a git branch.

For the previous I found that I can do:

`git reset --hard HEAD~1`

And probably alias that in a `git prev` or something, but I can't find out how to move "up" to the next commit.

And ideal solution would use 2 alias `git prev` and `git next`.

Thanks

Comment: `git reset --hard HEAD~1` is destructive; it discards all commit contents after the second-most recent commit (e.g., the most recent commit and any changes in the index and working copies). `git checkout` is the command you should use.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Referencing the child of a commit in Git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761825/referencing-the-child-of-a-commit-in-git)

Comment: And what do you want to happen if you're in a merge commit (multiple parents), or in a commit which is the parent of multiple commits? A git repository is like a DAG and branches are just pointers into this graph, so unless you have a linear history, 'previous' and 'next' are not necessarily well-defined.

Comment: What are you really trying to do? If you happen to be looking for a a commit which introduces a problem (or fixes one, for that matter), you actually want to be using `git bisect`, which helps you do a binary search.

Comment: @hammar let's just keep it simple and assume a linear history

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a handy alias setup by git called ORIG_HEAD which keeps track of the last head used.  So when you do a git reset --hard HEAD~1 the data about the head you just reset away from is stored in ORIG_HEAD.

so alias git prev to git reset --hard HEAD~1 (or HEAD^1)
and alias git next to git reset --hard ORIG_HEAD

Comment: This almost does it, the problem is when trying to do `git next` two times

Comment: Also, your "git prev" does not work properly when there are multiple developer contributing to the repo. It jumps to prevous commit made by the same developer.