# want to automatically squash 20 commits

Tags: git, squash

My topic branch is about 20 commits ahead of where I branched from.

I would like to automatically squash all these commits into the first commit
after the branch.

I know I can do this interactively with rebase, but I don't want to interact, just fire
off the command.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I find the first commit of a branch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15948202/how-can-i-find-the-first-commit-of-a-branch)

Comment: @Chronial: Maybe, but the title of the question you referred to is so misleading...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it this way:

```
git reset --soft HEAD~20
git commit -m "massive commit"
```

- The first command moves your topic branch 20 commits back, but
  preserves the changes in the index (and the working tree)
- Then you create a single commit with all the
  changes.

A quick way to find the exact commit you want to reset to is to do

```
git merge-base <topicbranch> <otherbranch>
```

If the output of that is `<commit-ish>`, you can then do

```
git reset --soft <commit-ish>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just check out your original branch, and `git merge --squash <other branch>`?

Then, `git commit` will give you a chance to edit the combined commit message.

Comment: A pretty good alternative, but it does leave the branches in a different state. The <otherbranch> will be at the point after the merge commit, and <topicbranch> will be left where it was. Unless you fix that with `git reset`s. of course.

Comment: I think I misread the question actually. I thought he meant the first commit on the original branch, after the branch was created; I think he wants to just squash his branch down to one commit without merging it.