# Is there any specific syntax to refer to forward commits (without using it's SHA1)?

Tags: git

I can refer to backwards revisions with `^` and `~*number*`, like `319411a^` or `HEAD~3`.

Is there any specific syntax to refer to forward commits (something like the syntax above)?

I'm **NOT** asking if it is possible to simply refer to forwards commits. I'm asking if it's possible to refer to forward revisions without manually finding out the desired revision SHA1.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I find the next commit in git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263674/how-do-i-find-the-next-commit-in-git), also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761825/referencing-the-child-of-a-commit-in-git

Comment: @Hasturkun none of these questions refer to a syntax for it. With both you have to find out the desired SHA1

Comment: @talles: There is no syntax for child/descendant commits, AFAIK. (also, the linked question refers to the syntax.) I'd also like to note [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2263779/20270) and suggest that you read the [gitrevisions manpage](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't; but, using `git rev-list` and then further work, it would be possible to find items that point back to a given commit.  You must first choose some starting point (probably `--all`), then exclude the target rev and its parents:

`git rev-list --all --not rev`

This of course produces a long list of revs, many of which are uninteresting, so it needs further filtering: you want those where a parent of the rev is *`rev`*.

This shell script (with no error checking etc) only handles first-parent:

```
target=$(git rev-parse $1)
git rev-list --all --not $target |
    while read rev; do
        if [ $(git rev-parse --verify --quiet $rev^) = $target ]; then
            echo $rev
        fi
    done
```

but it should be pretty obvious how to fancy it up from there (see the documentation for `git rev-list`).  Use:

```
git rev-list -1 --parents $rev
```

to turn a single rev into a list of "the rev and its parents", for merges, e.g.:

```
set -- $(git rev-list -1 --parents $rev)
shift # discard the rev itself
echo there are $# parents and they are $*
for parent do
    if [ $parent = $target ]; then
        echo $rev has $target as a parent
    fi
done
```

---

Edit: in a large repo, you can get a better starting point with `git branch --contains` (as noted by [RainerBlome in "referencing the child of a commit"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5353204/1256452).  Note that you need to parse away the `*` indicating current branch, and if you have HEAD "detached" the "current branch" is "no branch" and you might want to add `HEAD` as a starting point.  Then, `git rev-list --parents | grep ...` is a quick way to find desirable refs.  I've used these suggestions to improve performance, etc.

Here's a complete script, with some error checking too; lightly tested.

```
#! /bin/sh
#
# git-rev-list-children.sh

find_branches()
{
        local target="$1"

        set -- $(git branch --contains $target |
            sed -e 's/^\* (.*)/HEAD/' -e 's/^[* ] //')
        case $# in
        0) echo "there are no branches containing $revname"; return 1;;
        esac
        echo $@
}

find_children()
{
        local target="$1"
        shift

        git rev-list --parents "$@" ^$target | grep " $target" |
            while read line; do
                set -- $line
                echo $1
            done
}

# add option parsing (--short?) here if desired
case $# in
0) echo "usage: git-rev-list-children <rev> ..." >&2; exit 1;;
esac

for revname do
        target=$(git rev-parse "$revname") || exit 1
        set -- $(find_branches "$revname" || exit 1)
        find_children "$target" "$@"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Git commit objects only have a parent pointer, and traversal is backwards only.  Commit may or may not have one or more "forward" commits.