# Find when a branch was merged

Tags: git, merge, branch

There are lots of scripts floating around on the internet for deleting already-merged branches [such as](http://stevenharman.net/git-clean-delete-already-merged-branches)

```
$ git branch --merged master | grep -v master | xargs -n 1 git branch -d
```

but I'd like to keep my branches around for a while before doing the cleanup. So:

**How can I find when a particular branch was merged?** I'd like to be able to get the hash and the date of the merge commit. Extra credit for the ability to pipe several branches in. I'm ultimately going for

```
$ git branch --merged master | [find dates for each]
    | [compare dates to arbitrary date] | [delete old merged branches]
```

I realize that the standard practice is to tag/delete branches that you want to keep around a little longer, but if I did that, I'd still be asking this question about the hash and time of the merge commit.

#### Edit:

I've been looking through [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263674/how-do-i-find-the-next-commit-in-git) [threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761825/referencing-the-child-of-a-commit-in-git/5353204), because it strikes me that I'm looking for the child commit of the branch reference. Unfortunately, as mentioned in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263674/how-do-i-find-the-next-commit-in-git#comment2239748_2264471), `--children` only *adds* the children to the commits returned by a `log` or `rev-list`, instead of only returning children.

Comment: I should check [Git 2.11's rev id changes](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8779351dd7ee54c6ef2a7007670bad75a86edc75) to see whether they can better answer this question.

Answer (score 3):

#### Update 2015-05-15

A better answer, directly referring to parent commits of a branch is this:

```sh
$ git rev-list -1 --format=%p <branch_name> | grep -v commit |
  xargs -I {} sh -c 'git rev-list -1 --format="%h %ct" {}' | grep -v commit
```

and you can still pipe all the branches merged to `master` into it:

```sh
$ git branch -a --merged master | grep -v master | 
  xargs -I {} sh -c 'git rev-list -1 --format=%p {}' | grep -v commit |
  xargs -I {} sh -c 'git rev-list -1 --format="%h %ct" {}' | grep -v commit
```

This may work even for branches that have become part of your tree from a fast-forward.

If there's an argument you can pass to `rev-list` that prevents you from having to `grep -v commit` each time, I'd be interested to know it.

**Note:** Instead of `grep -v master`, I search for branch names that match `issue`. If you are looking to include or exclude specific branches, you should do the same.

---

#### Original

To get the hash, it seems you can do the following:

```sh
$ git log --ancestry-path --merges --format=%H <branch_name>..master | tail -1
```

or you could replace the format with whatever format you were looking for. The `--merges` just reduces the number of lines returned before we pick the last one.

You can pipe the list of merged branches with:

```sh
$ git branch -a --merged master | grep -v master |
  xargs -I {} sh -c 'git log --ancestry-path --format=%H --merges {}..master | tail -1'
```

but I haven't done the actual pruning. =)

Comment: I have discovered that this does not work if `<branch_name>` is not merged directly into `master` (although it works fine for my workflow). If someone has comments, improvements, better (more general) solutions, etc., please post!

Answer (score 1):

It may be too trivial, but what about starting with your merge history with something like

```
git log --merges --name-status --date=iso --pretty=format:"%C(auto)%h%d%Creset %C(cyan)(%cd)%Creset %C(green)%cn <%ce>%Creset %s"
```

Couldn't you extract the info from that output?

Comment: The branch name itself doesn't necessarily appear in the commit message, and I don't typically FF a branch to the merge commit onto `master`(or `main`).