# Show latest future commit with git rev-parse HEAD?

Tags: git

`git rev-parse HEAD` show the current commit (commit the branch is "reset" to). But how do I get the last future commit regardless of "reset" commit?

Edit:
`git log --all -1 --pretty=format:"%H"` seem to work, but do I really have to use a different command for this simple task?

Edit2: no, this does not work. It display 03317b1d158cd8a79ff4083884eaf3a2eee3b136, a commit between the last and the current...

Context:
In TortoiseGit i select some old revision and select `Reset "master" to this`
this = 051741bc532257903f3563d7d89c69cfdddaaf17
Latest commit = 19747382e3680bd90689e998834b492aa66c0730
After I do this, `git rev-parse HEAD` display 051741bc532257903f3563d7d89c69cfdddaaf17
How can I make it display 19747382e3680bd90689e998834b492aa66c0730?

Comment: No `reset` involved in `rev-parse HEAD`. Can you give a bit more context? *(But to answer your next question, no you can't dynamically refer to a commit's children, only parents.)*

Comment: What do you mean by "latest _future_ commit"?

Comment: Future commits, by definition, don't exist yet. Commits get assigned their hash ID at the time you make them, by computing a checksum of their complete contents (which include the time stamp of the time when you make them). So future commits don't have hash IDs. I think you don't *mean* "future" commit at all.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're laboring under a misconception here.  In particular you *do not want* to use `git reset` in the first place.  Having done so, you may need to use it again to fix the problem.

Note that `git rev-parse master` turns the name `master` into a commit hash ID.  It does so by following the six-step process outlined in [the gitrevisions documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions).  This finds that `master` is short for `refs/heads/master` and that `refs/heads/master` identifies one particular commit, so, after all that work, it's that commit hash ID that `git rev-parse` produces.

The special name `HEAD` *is* always the current commit.  But it may *be* the current commit in one of two ways:

- The special name contains the (full) name of a branch, e.g., `cat .git/HEAD` produces `ref: refs/heads/master`.  Then the name `refs/heads/master` actually holds the ID of the current commit, and `git rev-parse HEAD` first reads `.git/HEAD` to find this fact, and then translates `refs/heads/master` to a hash ID.

  That commit *is* the current commit.
- Or, the special name `HEAD` contains a raw commit hash ID.  That is, `cat .git/HEAD` produces a big ugly hash ID.  You are in what Git calls *detached HEAD* mode, and `git rev-parse HEAD` produces that same hash ID.

  That commit *is* the current commit.

Note that this means that there are two ways you can ask Git about `HEAD`.  One way is to ask: *What branch name does `HEAD` hold?*  This question has an answer only if `HEAD` is not detached.  The second way is to ask: *What commit hash ID does `HEAD` mean?*  This question almost always has an answer.<sup>1</sup>

In any case, each commit stores the hash ID of its immediate predecessor, or *parent* commit (or commits if it has more than one immediate predecessor).  Most commits have just one parent.  So given a commit hash ID, you can easily go *backwards*.  But you cannot go *forwards*, because a commit is frozen forever once it's made.  The ID of any commit made *after* that commit is not available within that commit.

This means that in general, what one does is keep a name *for* the latest commit.  Using the name, we can walk back, one commit at a time, to an earlier commit.  If we want to use that commit, we use the detached HEAD mode to do that.  And, if we are in detached HEAD mode, we can go back to the name to find the *latest* commit, then step backwards one commit at a time until we reach the detached-HEAD commit.  Whatever commit we were on just *before* we stepped back to this commit, that's the next commit *in the direction of the given name.*

I think a picture makes this much clearer:

```
                I <-J   <-- br1
               /
... <-F <-G <-H   <-- HEAD
               \
                K <-L   <-- br2
```

Here we're in detached HEAD mode, with `HEAD` containing some hash ID `H`.  So the current commit is just `H` itself.  But there are two possible *next* commits.  Starting from `br1` we'll go to commit `J`, which says to go back to `I`, which says to go back to `H`.  Or, starting from `br2`, we are at `L` which says to go back to `K` which says to go back to `H`.  So the *next commit forward* after `H` is *either* `K` *or* `L`, and it's impossible to say which unless you pick the ending-point.

To pick the ending point, it's best to leave both `br1` and `br2` alone, so that they continue to point to `J` and `L` respectively.  If we peel the label `br1` off `J` and make it point to `H`, we won't know how to find `I` and `J` any more.

> ... In TortoiseGit i select some old revision and select `Reset "master" to this`

You did not mention TortoiseGit initially (nor in your tags) and I have never used it, but [this web page](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-reset.html) implies that this reset invokes `git reset`.

What `git reset` does—well, one of many things it can do, and what it does for this particular case—is *change the hash ID stored in a branch name*.  So if branch name `master`, whose full name is `refs/heads/master`, contained `19747382e3680bd90689e998834b492aa66c0730` before, but then you have Git overwrite it with `051741bc532257903f3563d7d89c69cfdddaaf17`, you no longer have `master` containing the number `19747382e3680bd90689e998834b492aa66c0730`.  If no *other* name contains that number, the only way you have to *remember* that number is, well, to write it down somewhere.

With command-line Git, you could then run `git reset master 19747382e3680bd90689e998834b492aa66c0730` to write that number back into `master`, since you have it written down.  This works, but is not a good plan in general—you should have been using, or at least started with, detached HEAD mode instead, to access and work with the commit whose real name is `051741bc532257903f3563d7d89c69cfdddaaf17`.  (How you might do that in TortoiseGit, I have no idea.)

If you have command line Git, you can do that now—probably you should completely shut down TortoiseGit first, so that it doesn't attempt to undo it.

Note that command-line Git automatically "writes down" the last few (or many) values it has stored under each branch name, in what Git calls the *reflog* for that branch.  From the command line you can run:

```
git reflog master
```

to view the contents of this log.  If you had not saved the number `19747382e3680bd90689e998834b492aa66c0730` anywhere yourself, this might be the way to recover it.  But, again, it's probably better to just use detached HEAD mode to examine old commits.

Note that after using detached HEAD mode to obtain and inspect some existing historical commit, you can create a *new* branch name *at* that commit so as to do new development starting from that point.  To do that, use `git branch` or `git checkout -b` from the command line.  The difference between the two is that `git checkout -b` first creates the new branch, then switches *to* it, so that `HEAD` contains the new branch name rather than the hash ID.  In other words:

```
git checkout -b newbranch
```

is equivalent to:

```
git branch newbranch
git checkout newbranch
```

The first step creates the branch, storing in it the hash ID that `git rev-parse HEAD` would obtain.  The second step stores that branch name *in* `HEAD`, so that `HEAD` contains `ref: refs/heads/newbranch`.  In the second step, the *currently checked out commit* did not change, but the *current branch* did.

Comment: What I would like is from a list of commits in my log, select arbitrary commit between the first and the last, make my code look like that commit (aka. active commit), repeat for the next arbitrary commit and so on. While I'm doing all of this jumping around between commits (changing the active commit), the last commit does not change. But it seems in git the last and the current commit must be the same (HEAD). Edit: I'm sorry but I'm completely new to git.

Comment: `HEAD` (the special, all-capitals name HEAD, not the lowercase string "head"  that you'll see elsewhere in documentation in phrases like "branch head") is in fact always the current commit. This is how Git defines "the current commit". But in *detached HEAD* mode, `HEAD` can rove across all your commits. Pay attention to the drawing too though! There's often no *linear* way to move about. Commits I and K are both immediately after commit H because of the branching structure of the commit graph.

Comment: Note that on Windows, because the OS insists that (e.g.) README.TXT is the same file as readme.txt, you can sometimes use all-lowercase `head`. This does not work on Linux, so if you plan to ever use both systems, don't fall into the habit of writing `head` instead of `HEAD`.

Comment: Ok, thanks. It will probably take a while until I understand the answer and can tell if this solve my problem:-)

Comment: BTW, for multiple tricks / ways to deal with this, see my (long, alas) answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39186879/1256452).