Quickly flip through Git commit history
I want to learn a new project, I need to constantly switch in the project's commit history so that I can view the code. First, I execute git switch --detach commit-hash to bring the project back to the first commit, but when I want to continue viewing the second commit, I execute git log, I find that there is only one commit in the commit history, and I have no way to switch. Is there a quick way to easily switch to the previous commit and the next commit? Please help me.

I've used https://stackoverflow.com/a/29424966/3001761 for the stated purpose, but this relies on a defined "end" to move towards.

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-switch%5D+previous

To return to the tip of the previous branch after git switch --detach commit do git switch branch-name. Or git switch -.

You can switch to the previous commit with
git switch HEAD~ --detach

This one works to select the next commit after b11b85aef in the main branch:
git switch --detach `git --no-pager log b11b85aef..main --pretty=format:"%h" | tail -n 1` 

The parts work as follows:

git --no-pager log b11b85aef..main --pretty=format:"%h" print the hashes of the all the commits from the branch end to the given commit, excluding the commit itself.
| tail -n 1 only pick the last row
enclosing that in back ticks makes it an argument to the git switch command.

To be honest I don't know what it will do if there are forks and merges in the branch.
I assume it will probably just silently pick one.
